# Says import not used. Now sound doesnt work

Tags: android

New to Android Dev and this site.
I created an app and basics were working.
I added a sound button and it worked.
I created a new app for earlier version of android and accidently dragged my Main Activity file to the new app instead of copying it. When I dragged it back, it said my imports were not used. Now the sound, which I had to do an 'import' statement for, does not work.
Heres the code.

```
package com.offthericta.wiferemote;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.offthericta.wiferemote.R;
import com.offthericta.wiferemote.R.id;
import com.offthericta.wiferemote.R.layout;
import com.offthericta.wiferemote.R.menu;
import com.offthericta.wiferemote.R.raw;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.v(TAG, "Initializing sounds...");
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.blah);

        Button Button03 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Button03);
        Button03.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Playing sound...");
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v){}

    public void disclaimerBTN (View v){
        Toast.makeText(this, "FAILED:   The remote object is not responding to this     command",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Lucifer - You removed code lines...

Comment: @user370305, they were unnecessary import files only.

Comment: @Lucifer _ How do you say they were unnecessary? Look at Question Subject...

Answer (score 2):

I think your main concern is these statements..

```
import com.offthericta.wiferemote.R;
import com.offthericta.wiferemote.R.id;
import com.offthericta.wiferemote.R.layout;
import com.offthericta.wiferemote.R.menu;
import com.offthericta.wiferemote.R.raw;
```

**You are accessing other Application Package's resources in your current Application Package.**

Just Use your current Application's Resource File.

Remove above import statements add necessary resources in your current project's resource directory. And compile and Run again..

Comment: Thank you replying. But I am very new to these kinds of languages. I've only ever done html, php, mysql coding. Is there any chance you could please explain exactly what I need to do? I dont even know what a resource file is, where to find it, or how to add what you say. Any tips are very greatly appreciated.